# How do I integrate Envoy proxy with Service Fabric?

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric, envoyproxy

How do I integrate Envoy proxy with Service Fabric? Is there a similar solution which is provided by Traefik https://github.com/jjcollinge/traefik-on-service-fabric? If not, what other alternative do I have? This is required for a Windows cluster in Service Fabric.

Comment: why dont you use traefic?

Comment: I was just checking various other options are available. recently envoy is also being used by azure service fabric mesh. so wanted to know if there are any offering for service fabric

Comment: This repo seems to do that: https://github.com/Microsoft/service-fabric-reverse-proxy

Comment: I saw that link but do not see any steps on how to use it

Comment: You could create an issue in that repo asking for guidance.

Answer (score 0):

I found a repository with Traefik as reverse proxy for Service Fabric

https://github.com/microsoft/service-fabric-traefik